# Power supply options for circuit

Tags: arduino, power-supply

[image: Circuit]
 So, I have the above circuit and I have to somehow integrate this into a mobile phone cover. So to power it, I was thinking of using a 3.7v 600mAH Li-Po battery. I want to integrate the battery into the cover in such a way that the cover becomes a rechargeable cover. As the Beetle needs 5V, I will need some sort of booster as well. The other alternative is to use 2 coin cell batteries that supply 3.3 V each.

Some more information on the project:

1. I am creating an interactive game and I basically want this circuit
   to act as an input to the game that will be played on a mobile
   phone.
2. The circuit has to fit into a mobile phone cover and the push
   buttons that you see on the circuit are to be placed on either side
   of the cover. Both buttons have to be pressed simultaneously to
   create the required action(s) in the game. I already have this part
   working.
3. In terms of how long I would like the battery to last between
   charges: a similar amount of time that a phone battery lasts (if
   that's any measure to put things into perspective)

I am not sure what the best solution for this will be; by best I mean the easiest and least complex to implement.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Hit the edit link below your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Since Beetle Bluno is based on ATMega328p, which can operate in a range of voltages from 2.7VDC to 5.5VDC, your board can most likely be powered from a single Li-Po battery, fed to the VCC, without any additional circuitry.

Comment: thank you for your response. How would I go about making it rechargeable ? Would using the TP4056 which is a lithium battery charger module be useful?